Payload CMS: 404 NOT found when routing to other pages after deploying on vercel
  Hello team, I am trying out Payload CMS and I have uploaded my payload app on vercel . When I open the deployed app its showing the welcome page but when I navigate to admin or dashboard I am getting a 404. also tried to use vercel.json but its not working. My server.ts file is under the src directory. https://positive-konnections-f6vphpuq9-moses-projects-a42870f9.vercel.app/.
Github link to see project structure --> https://github.com/Geek-Squared/positive-konnections-api
Here's my vercel.json


{
    "version": 2,
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "src/server.ts"
        }
    ]
}



